# Vipassana report on breathing

Tags: meditation

In the vipassana practice, my teacher asks me to give a detailed report of one of my breathing rise and falling. I've tried but he tells me that the report is too general, that I need to provide more details. Can someone give me an example of a detailed report? Here it is mine. Some feedback?

Rise:
1- the belly starts to rise slowly, with ease
2- then it speeds up and takes in a lot of air
3- I feel a resistance, belly is close to the maximum volume, but the breathing goes on and it even hurts a bit. It slows down and stops.

Falling:
1- breath out very fast from the beginning. I feel a relieve on the belly.
2- continue to breath out fast
3- I feel there is not much air left and I feel a resistance on the belly, pain again, until it slows down and stops.

Comment: LOL this is cheating, no one should reply! Do your own homework! :))

Comment: Hihihi, I am not trying to cheat. I am trying to see what could I focus on. For instance, the teacher asked me if I feel great or cold, but that's not the case. What else can I focus on?

Comment: Ask that teacher if you don't understand the questions, tell him the truth about your confusion. Vipassana is about truth. Dealing with frustration about the teacher is a part of the learning; face that truth as well, don't escape to forums. Be offline, focus on meditation, that alone is the training.

Answer (score 3):

This is not for other people to answer.

This is your own work. Only we ourselves can work and develop ourselves.

It can actually be harmful for a meditator to hear what lies ahead on the path before he or she has attained those fruits. That is because the Mind can then try to search for the things one has heard or read. That is not good. They should come naturally as practice develops.

Go meditate and find your answers or ask your teacher if you do not understand the practice or technique.

Answer (score 0):

Your teachers seems in the wrong to me.

There is no giving a good description for these things. How can one be expected to describe the mirriad of sensations, workings of attention, succesive arising of knowledges and shifting of focus to fleeting disctractions according to conscious and unconsciouss volition on a moment to moment basis.

Ill go ahead and start with arising of Body-Consciousness which lasts about how many smallest units of what can be called time, and we are not 0.0001 of a second in, not even close probably.

It is way different every time.

Maybe that is what he is trying to make you see, he could tell you probably make it more clear to you so you dont have to ask strangers.

Answer (score 0):

Your master telling you that your meditation not progress. And when I consider your detail I think I know what is the cause makes your meditation not progress. It is because of wrong meditation's procedure.

In tipitaka and commentary, vipassanā-meditation never has special activity like that. Vipassanā-meditation analyses everything as 5 aggregates, etc, then it focuses on these 5 aggregates' 3 characteristics.

So, what you trying to do is not vipassanā-meditation in tipitaka and commentary. It looks like ānāpānassati-samatha-meditation, but you looks confusing it's procedure. Therefore, I advise you to read [ānāpānassati-samatha-meditation, here](https://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/search/label/%C4%80n%C4%81p%C4%81nassati).

The other advising, you should not focus on belly, you should focus only on your breath at the tip of nose.